# Two pairs of consecutive values list python

Tags: python, list

If you have a list in python like this:
`list1 = [(1,2), (3,1), (4,1), (1,2), (3,1)]`
If you have `list1` in python and you want to find if two pairs of
consecutive values in a list in python are equal like (1,2) and
(3,1) is repeated twice and you want to update a variable lets say
`i` to 2 based on this.
How would you do this in python?

Comment: Do you have a first attempt you can share? Maybe we can see if there's a particular knowledge gap

Comment: You have a couple of problems to solve: you want to find duplicate pairs, so you'll have to figure out how to get those pairs to begin with. It's unclear what your variable `i` represents, does it count all different pairings? Or do you need a counter per pairing? What have you tried yourself? What problems did you have?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got it, looped through the original list and made mini lists of every each pair, then I checked to see if that pair occurs twice.

```
lst = [(1,2), (3,1), (4,1), (1,2), (3,1)]

#iterate through list and append each pair of values
tmp = []
for i in range(0, len(lst)-1):
    tmp.append(lst[i] + lst[i+1])

#see if any of the pairs appear twice, if so add to new list and get the length of that list to be your count
output =  [x for x in tmp if tmp.count(x) > 1]
i = len(output)
print(i)
```

Comment: You could use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and `sum` to make this cleaner. `count = Counter((list1[i], list1[i+1]) for i in range(len(list1)-1)); i = sum(n > 1 for n in count.values())`